# Remove Ubuntu to downgrade

Tags: uninstall, downgrade

I'm trying to remove ubuntu so I can downgrade to a more stable release (I grabbed the latest one, it's crashtacular but I really like it when it works).

It's a single boot system. I have the USB key I used to install it in the first place but when I boot from it it doesn't have an option that jumps out for me as being something that would remove ubuntu.  There's one that says 'Ubuntu with a version number. I tried that, it just makes the system boot into ubuntu off the hard drive.  The other option is a mem test.

Is there a command I can enter or do I need to make a different usb key?  All I want to do is clear it right off, I'm not concerned with saving anything. I just want to blow the whole thing out and then reinstall from scratch.  The install process was really really really easy.  The uninstall process is oddly complex and difficult if google is an indication.

I may just give up, take the drive out and use a windows system to format it but I think having to do that is a bit ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Just [create a new USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) with the Ubuntu version you want to use and boot from that stick. The installer has an option to install Ubuntu using the **whole disk**. Using that option will automatically format your hard drive, thus removing the old installation of Ubuntu.

**Warning**: Make sure to backup any files you want to keep, since your home directory will be gone afterwards, too.